# reading custom web service on SharePoint 2010

Tags: jquery, soap, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have a requirement to be able to pull data from a repeating table on an InfoPath form and put it into a report. I found a solution file on Codeplex that will read the data out of the repeating table and output it as XML via a SOAP query. I'm trying to read the SOAP query and output it to a web page via JQuery in a CEWP. I'm fairly new to trying this and I'm a little lost on how to approach this. The web service presents this example code:

```
POST /_vti_bin/InfoPathDB/InfoPathDB.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.158.2.5 
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap12:Body>
    <QueryFormLibrary xmlns="http://infopathdb.codeplex.com/">
      <SiteURL>string</SiteURL>
      <FormLibraryTitle>string</FormLibraryTitle>
      <OptionalContentType>string</OptionalContentType>
      <OptionalCAMLFilter>string</OptionalCAMLFilter>
      <OptionalBooleanIncludeAttachments>string</OptionalBooleanIncludeAttachments>
    </QueryFormLibrary>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <QueryFormLibraryResponse xmlns="http://infopathdb.codeplex.com/">
      <QueryFormLibraryResult>xml</QueryFormLibraryResult>
    </QueryFormLibraryResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I'm a bit confused by which part needs to go where in my JQuery code. The code block I'm trying to adapt this to is:

```
<script src="/Site_Assets/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
        var soapEnv =
            <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <QueryFormLibrary xmlns="http://infopathdb.codeplex.com/">
      <SiteURL>http://255.255.255.1</SiteURL>
      <FormLibraryTitle>List Entries</FormLibraryTitle>
      <OptionalContentType></OptionalContentType>
      <OptionalCAMLFilter></OptionalCAMLFilter>
      <OptionalBooleanIncludeAttachments></OptionalBooleanIncludeAttachments>
    </QueryFormLibrary>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: "/_vti_bin/InfoPathDB/InfoPathDB.asmx HTTP/1.1",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: processResult,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    });

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
                            var iDesc=$(this).attr("FieldOne");
                            var iResp=$(this).attr("FieldTwo");
            var iID=$(this).attr("ows_ID");   
            var liHtml = "<div class='question' id='"+iID+"'>" + iDesc + "</div><div class='answer' id='a"+iID+"'>"+ iResp +"</a></div>";
                            $("#entries").append(liHtml);
}</script>

<div id="entries">&#160;</div>
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong/right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok- I figured it all out, after much flailing around, and some support from the author of the web service. I'm using JSON to fetch my data.

Here is the successful block of code:

```
<script>
function getJSON(SiteURL, FormLibraryTitle, OptionalContentType, OptionalCAMLFilter, OptionalBooleanIncludeAttachments) {
var test;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/_vti_bin/InfoPathDB/InfoPathDB.asmx/QueryFormLibraryAsJSON",
        data: "{'SiteURL': '" + SiteURL + "', 'FormLibraryTitle': '" + FormLibraryTitle + "', 'OptionalContentType':'" + OptionalContentType + "', 'OptionalCAMLFilter':'" + OptionalCAMLFilter + "', 'OptionalBooleanIncludeAttachments':'" + OptionalBooleanIncludeAttachments + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
        // Save for F15 Developer Tools to see
            test = JSON.parse(msg.d);
            outputJSON(test);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr);
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

This is what feeds my output function which takes the (test) object and feeds the selected elements into an HTML table.